# Adobe Flash Interactive map

Tags: flash, dictionary, adobe, interactive

We want to create interactive map with india map.

Similar to the below one

http://elections.nytimes.com/2008/results/president/map.html

can anybody help us? any tutorial is available

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google maps flash api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/intro.html). With it you are able to do stuff like [this](http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/StateMap/StateMap.html) ([source code](http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/StateMap/srcview/index.html)). But don't forget to turn off ability to zoom in/out the map.